# JSON:API returns the body field as format, processed, and value: How to get only processed?

Tags: 9

When using JSON:API, the body field of a node (article) is returned like this:

```
body: {
  format: "basic_html",
  processed: "<p>blah blah blah</p>",
  value: "blah blah blah"
}
```

However, I just want to return `body: "<p>blah blah blah</p>"` (the value of `processed`).

What hook or class method should I use to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) module includes this feature.

1. Enable JSON:API Extras resource overrides for Articles at `/admin/config/services/jsonapi/resource_types`.
2. On the Article resource override, for the body field, click **Advanced**, then **Single Nested Property**, and enter **processed** as the value.

You can use this technique to drill down into any properties you need, not just the values of text fields.

Warning: [Using a Field Enhancer on a field will break POST if you POST to the field alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras/issues/3305076).  Workaround: POST to the actual field name, not the alias.

Many thanks to xaviemirmon in the #decoupled Slack for telling me about this.